# PHP + NGINX generate ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Tags: php, apache, magento, nginx

Since a few days I've been getting ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE errors at some of the website I host. There is one Magento where the admin panel doesn't even show any more, just ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE. The setup:

NGINX proxy -> Apache -> PHP-FPM 5.6

What happens:

- Request shows up in Apache log
- Request shows up in PHP-FPM access log
- Request does not show up in nginx log and no data is sent back from nginx

When I add `die('test')` to the top of the index.php, the content shows. The non-admin parts of the Magento website work fine. Something in the Magento admin panel breaks PHP-FPM it seems. But, PHP-FPM does show the entry in the access log with status 200?

PHP-FPM access log:

```
18/Nov/2016:22:13:06 +0100 "GET /index.php" 200 945.396ms 31232kb 94.14%
18/Nov/2016:22:13:07 +0100 "GET /index.php" 200 882.143ms 31488kb 96.36%
18/Nov/2016:22:13:08 +0100 "GET /index.php" 200 880.647ms 31232kb 97.66%
```

Apache access log:

```
141.138.139.40 - - [18/Nov/2016:22:13:08 +0100] "GET /index.php/motornl/mobile/history/key/5aa86290fcd9cc207fb7c0a4e5a2a326/ HTTP/1.0" 200 8854 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.98 Safari/537.36"
```

Also, no errors show up in PHP-error logs or any other logs I have. If I manually generate fatal / parse errors; they do show up in the logs.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: does it show the page if you call apache directly, bypassing nginx? ex: using apache port on the url

Comment: @peixotorms hm, this does indeed work. This helps a lot; I will search from here now!

Comment: If that works, you just have to check if your upstream block is calling the right port. Ex: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-nginx-as-a-reverse-proxy-for-apache